# Need help to breakdown a string

Tags: c#, string, parsing, grammar, rule-engine

I'm trying to split a string in C# to make it a logic for my code. The string is:

```
if ( x111 > 0 ) 
   then (( x111/ x222) >= 34 and ( x222 / x222) <= 4500) 
else ( if ( x333 equals 0) 
   then true else false)
```

I'm using the following code for other strings and it works fine:

```
string query = "if ( x111 > 0 ) then (x222 > 0 ) else true";
string result = query.Split(new string [] {"if", "then", "else" },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

**Output:**

> ( x111 > 0 ) 
>  (x222 > 0 ) 
>  true

For my above string, there is an issue that **then** condition contains another nested logic and I need to split it to make a logic. Can I split it based on **"("** and **")"** so that I'll be able to store the results for various expressions like **if, then, else** and nested conditions.

Comment: There's probably something wrong with your approach/architecture if you're trying to write your own parser....  what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: what should be the outpuit of string 
if ( x111 > 0 ) 
   then (( x111/ x222) >= 34 and ( x222 / x222) <= 4500) 
else ( if ( x333 equals 0) 
   then true else false) ????

Comment: Just curious, but you may try [`(?<=(?:if|then|else)\s*)(?:\((?>[^()]+|\((?<number>)|\)(?<-number>))*(?(number)(?!))\)|\w+)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d(%3f%3aif%7cthen%7celse)%5cs*)(%3f%3a%5c((%3f%3e%5b%5e()%5d%2b%7c%5c((%3f%3cnumber%3e)%7c%5c)(%3f%3c-number%3e))*(%3f(number)(%3f!))%5c)%7c%5cw%2b)&i=if+(+x111+%3e+0+)+%0d%0a+++then+((+x111%2f+x222)+%3e%3d+34+and+(+x222+%2f+x222)+%3c%3d+4500)+%0d%0aelse+(+if+(+x333+equals+0)+%0d%0a+++then+true+else+false)). However, I think you really need to write your own parser.

Comment: Please don't make your question a moving target. Please ask a new question with your edit text.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to build a parser using string operations... That is a bad idea and will probably never work.

I suggest you to use [ANTLR](http://antlr.org), a tool built to create grammars and parser/lexers. You should give it a try. There are many examples of languages, including C#, which you can use as a start for your own language parser.

Comment: All I'm trying to do is to convert a business rule into a C# logic. So trying to break down the expressions of different statements and then store them into the database. But the above formula is quite complex. Should I try to count theindex of "(" and ")" and then split the string.

Comment: @iSahilSharma a statement like "all I'm trying to do is" doesn't mean the task is easy. "All I'm trying to do is climb Mt. Everest..." Parsing a grammar is very tricky and rather than doing it by hand, why not use a tool like ANTLR that does the heavy lifting for you? You're saying "All I'm trying to do is climb Mt. Everest... with no oxygen tanks and I'll find food and shelter along the way" We're saying "All I'm trying to do is climb Mt. Everest... so I'm packing the best supplies and hiring the most experienced Sherpa in the world" Which one makes more sense?